# How to consider the "loader class" with MVC pattern?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I'm creating a Java project (with JavaFX) and I'm trying to use the **MVC pattern** as much as I can. I found some examples online that not only use manager and controller classes (e.g. `XyzController` and `XyzManager`), but also a **loader class** (e.g. `XyzLoader`). As I'm using JavaFX I was considering all my `.fxml` files as part of the view. **How do I have to consider the loader classes?** As part of the view as well? Or part of my `controller` package?

Here's an example of a simple loader:

```
public class AboutLoader {

    public void load() {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/about_screen.fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("About us");
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a plumbing code. Patterns are not set in stone, so don't worry too much about that.

Looking at this particular one I'd say it's more of the View nature as it sets window title and behavior and knows nothing about content (model).